# Go to changes in Google Spreadsheet (or Docs)

Tags: google-sheets

When I see that somebody has changed a document I am working on in Google Drive, I normally want to see where exactly the change happened. Using File > See Revision History... is not really helpful when the document is large or I have multiple sheets in a spreadsheet.

Isn't there some function that allows me to jump to the change in the document, so I can immediately follow what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the history revision in Google Docs Editors, don't include a jump to the tracked changes, just a color highlighting and strikethrough for deletions.

By the other hand, recently was launched a "suggestion mode". It inserts a comment automatically. They could be navigated through the comments panel.

An alternative could be use Google Apps Script to insert a comment or note on changes.

**References**
[See the history of changes made to a file - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?hl=en)
[Suggest edits in a document - Docs Help Editor](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6033474?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

By now, the revision history shows you the total number of changes for the selected revision and gives you an option to jump to the next/previous change. I tested this for docs not for spreadsheets.